# volatile and synchronized on single core cpu (example - pentium pro)

Tags: java, multithreading, assembly, cpu, volatile

I have read and know in detail in the implications of the Java volatile and synchronized keyword at the cpu level in SMP architecture based CPUs.

A great paper on that subject is here:

http://irl.cs.ucla.edu/~yingdi/web/paperreading/whymb.2010.06.07c.pdf

Now, leave SMP cpus aside for this question. My question is: How does volatile and synchronized keyword work as it relates to older single core CPUs. Example a Pentium I/Pro/II/III/earlier IVs.

I want to know specifically:

1) Is the L1-L2 caches not used to read memory addresses and all reads and writes are  performed directly to main memory? If yes why? (Since there is only a single cache copy and no need for coherency protocols, why can't the cache be directly used by two threads that are time slicing the single core CPU ?). This is me asking this question after reading dozens of internet forums about how volatile reads and writes to/from the "master copy in main memory".

2) Apart from taking a lock on the this or specified object which is more of a Java platform thingy, what other effects does the synchronized keyword have on single core CPUs (compilers, assembly, execution, cache) ?

3) With a non superscalar CPU (Pentium I), instructions are not re-ordered. So if that is the case, then is volatile keyword required while running on a Pentium 1? (atomicity, visibility and ordering would be a "no problemo" right, because there is only one cache, one core to work on the cache, and no re-ordering).

Comment: Well, both keywords prevent reordering; it is guaranteed for instance that writes to a volatile variable "happen-before" any subsequent read of that variable; it also prevents the use of thread local storage for such a variable but I'm not sure this applies to such old CPUs

Comment: I am sure we all have our problems to solve. :).

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is the L1-L2 caches not used to read memory addresses and all reads and writes are performed directly to main memory?

No. The caches are still enabled. That's not related to SMP.

> 2) Apart from taking a lock on the this or specified object which is more of a Java platform thingy, what other effects does the synchronized keyword have on single core CPUs (compilers, assembly, execution, cache) ?
>
> 3) Does anything change with respect to a superscalar/non superscalar architecture (out-of-order) processor w.r.t these two keywords?

Gosh, do you have to ask this question about *Java*? Remember that all things eventually boil down to good ol' fashioned machine instructions.  I'm not intimitely familiar with the guts of Java synchronization, but as I understand it, `synchronized` is just syntactic sugar for your typical monitor-style synchronization mechanism. Multiple threads are not allowed in a critical section simultaneously. Instead of simply spinning on a spinlock, the scheduler is leveraged - the waiting threads are *put to sleep*, and woken back up when to lock is able to be taken again.

The thing to remember is that even on a single-core, non-SMP system, you *still* have to worry about OS preemption of threads! These threads can be scheduled on and off of the CPU whenever the OS wants to. This is the purpose for the locks, of course.

Again, this question is so much better asked under the context of assembly, or even C (whose compiled result can often times be directly inferred) as opposed to Java, which has to deal with the VM, JITted code, etc.

Comment: "even on a single-core, non-SMP system, you still have to worry about OS preemption of threads" - yes, but if there is only one cache - why should there be a problem with visibility, ordering or atomicity?

Comment: user3579905: Suppose thread I removes the head of a linked list A,B,C by (1) setting A's link to null and (2) updating the list's head pointer to B. If the OS schedules thread II before (1) but after (2), a bug will result; thread II will see a linked list consisting of only A, even though thread I never thought the linked list was in that state.

Comment: @user3579905: because the JVM’s HotSpot optimizer is allowed to do reorderings. A CPU has *registers* to hold frequently or recently used values which are accessed way faster than data from memory, even from cache. The JIT might emit code which holds values in these registers and reorderings might make their use more efficient. Hence these registers act like a thread-private cache with the same implication as a core-local cache on an SMP machine. Thus, correct thread synchronization is even relevant to my 1986 old Amiga…

Comment: @JoseTorres - that is mutual exclusion (brought to you by the synchronized keyword by taking a lock on a global object).

Comment: @Holger - yep - that would explain it. Thank you. Another reason that I thought of was a 64 bit long mutation would be two 32 bit mutations in a x86-32, and Hotspot or assembler would be at liberty to move them around as long as it different affect the global order of a single thread, but during concurrent executions those assumptions would fail big time.